# How to select all checkboxes that are denoted by a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question div which looks like so:

```
<div  class="Q">
<div id="Q1"><span>1. </span>Which of the following have the same meaning?</div>
<div class="A"><input type="checkbox"  id="Q1A1Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Q1A1User" class="UserA"/><span id="Q1A1Text">String</span></div> 
<div class="A"><input type="checkbox"  id="Q1A2Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Q1A2User" class="UserA"/><span id="Q1A2Text">string</span></div>
<div class="A"><input type="checkbox" id="Q1A3Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Q1A3User" class="UserA"/><span id="Q1A3Text">Integer</span></div>
<div class="A"><input type="checkbox"  id="Q1A4Correct" /><input type="checkbox" id="Q1A4User" class="UserA"/><span id="Q1A4Text">int</span></div>
</div>
```

And I also have a two dimensional array which denotes the type of each question and it's correct answers, e.g.

```
var correctAnswers=[["multipleAnswer","1","2"],["multipleAnswer","2","3"]];
```

Denotes that questions 1 and 2 (first two element in the array) are multiple answer questions (let's assume that's the only kind), and their correct answers are 1 and 2 for question 1, and 2 and 3 for question 2.
Now I need to check each checkbox which is a correct answer (i.e. for question 1 - `Q1A1Correct` and `Q1A2Correct`).
I managed doing that for a specific question:

```
    var correctAs={};
    correctAs.Q1 = ["checkbox","1","2"];

    $('#checkAs').click(function(){
        $.each(correctAs.Q1,function()
        { 
            $("#Q1A"+this+"Correct").attr('checked', true);
        }); //mark correct As according to array above            

});
```

But I can't generalize my code so that it will work with the two dimensional array.

So my question is - how do I check all correct answers for all questions given the array? (changing the way the array is built is an option if that'll be helpful)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var correctAnswers = [["multipleAnswer","1","2"], ["multipleAnswer","2","3"]];

$('#checkAs').click(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0, len = correctAnswers.length; i < len; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, ln = correctAnswers[i].length; j < ln; j++) {
            if (!isNaN(Number(correctAnswers[i][j]))) {
                $('#Q' + (i+1) + 'A' + correctAnswers[i][j] + 'Correct')
                    .attr('checked', true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/6QLbb/)